# Paraphrasing a sentence with post modifier

Tags: meaning, paraphrasing, post-modifier

I wrote the sentence B for paraphrasing sentence A.

> A: I feel scared, because my girlfriend is obsessive about me.
>
> B: I'm afraid of my girlfriend being obsessive about me.

Having written B, I am suddenly confused whether sentence B really means sentence A or sentence C below, because be+being+adjective is used for temporal change of subject.

> C: I feel scared, when my girlfriend becomes obsessive about me.

Can sentence B replace sentence A, C or neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three sentences mean different things.

The first explains why you feel scared - the reason for your fear. Your girlfriend is already obsessive about you.

The second expresses your concern about an undesired development - that your girlfriend may become obsessive about you. At present she is not obsessive about you.

The third states that your are fearful **at such times** as your girlfriend becomes obsessive about you. When she is not obsessive, you are not scared. This suggests that your girlfriend goes through phases of being obsessive.

(PS: None of your sentences requires a comma.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, I'm wondering if being in sentence B is left out, does it change meaning?

Comment: If you omit the word **being**, the sentence is no longer grammatical.